# Add a timestamp to Firebase "push" method

Tags: javascript, firebase

dataRef is a reference to my Firebase (Javascript web app) and this works perfectly:

```
dataRef.child('comments').push({
    comment:comment,
    username:username
});
```

I want to add a Firebase server-generated timestamp to my "push", so I tried this:

```
dataRef.child('comments').push({
    comment:comment,
    username:username,
    timestamp:firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

That gives me an error, though. The [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html) explains how to use it, but I'm not getting it. Is there a syntax modification I can make that will make this work properly?

Comment: The name of the variable is `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. In the snippet, your first `f` is lowercase. If that is really your code, it is simply a typo in that code. If the typo is not there in your actual code, you'll have a be a bit more specific about the error message you're getting.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I guess I didn't realize it would be that picky.

Answer (score 5):

Use firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

Use can also use `{'.sv': 'timestamp'}`

**Example:**

```
ref.child('hello').push({
    world: {'.sv': 'timestamp'}
    // world: 1534932030738
});
```